# Error ORA-01722 when updating a table using ODP.net

Tags: c#, oracle, parameters, sql-update, odp.net

I'm trying update a table that looks something like:

```
column a VARCHAR2(80)
```

Using the following function:

```
sqlString = "UPDATE TABLE SET domicilio = :p_domicilio WHERE codigo = :p_codigo";
string sqlCommandtext = sqlString; 
using (var cn = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=XXX..."))
{
    cn.Open();

    using (OracleCommand commandInt32 = cn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = sqlCommandtext;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_codigo", OracleDbType.Int32, 34620, ParameterDirection.Input);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_domicilio", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = domicilio;
        //cmd.Parameters.Add("p_domicilio", OracleDbType.Varchar2, domicilio, ParameterDirection.Input);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

but get "**ORA-01722 invalid number**" exception.

I try

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_domicilio", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = domicilio;
```

and

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_domicilio", OracleDbType.Varchar2, domicilio, ParameterDirection.Input);
```

and

```
    var pDomicilio = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter()
    {
        DbType = DbType.String,
        Value = domicilio,
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
        OracleDbType = Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2,
        ParameterName = "p_domicilio",
    };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, ODP.Net binds parameters by the Order they are provided, not by name, and you are specifying the second parameter `codigo` before the first parameter `domicilio`. Bind by order means the name of the parameter is ignored.

Either change the command [Binding to Name](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/OracleCommandClass.htm#DAFCJDDG) (`cmd.BindByName = true`), or provide the parameters in the same order that they are used in your command.

If this is a big project, I would suggest creating a factory plumbing method for returning `OracleCommand`s which will be set to `BindByName`

Comment: Alternatively you can set bindbyname on by default in your web.config settings per https://stackoverflow.com/a/44928408/863651

Comment: OK, where in the GO4 book do they call it factory plumbing method!  I love it.  Created one in my ignorance and now it has a name.  Upvoted!
BTW - I ALWAYS (that is, most of the time) use BindByName with Oracle - why risk forgetting the column order or whatever?

Comment: Ok, I'll pray to GO4 for forgiveness for blaspheming. How about "Factory Method, defined in boilerplate code" :D. But XDS's link looks like a pretty good global `Mjölnir` alternative