# Execute Stored Procedure With Nameless Parameters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I was just wondering if there is a way to execute a stored procedure with out naming the parameters. Meaning that C# resolves the parameters in the order they're declared within the stored procedure.

```
public static DataTable GetRelatedResources(string StoredProcedure, object[] Parameters)
{
   var Results = new DataTable();

   try
   {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MK3Entities"].ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = StoredProcedure;

                if (Parameters!= null)
                {
                   foreach(var Param in Parameters)
                   { 
                       // I Want To Do something like this
                       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(Param);
                   }
                }

                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.Fill(Results);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       MMSLogger.Instance.WriteToLog("Exception Executing Stored Procedure:" + ex.Message);
    }

    return Results;
}
```

Comment: No; but you can call `DeriveParameters` to have the required parameters loaded dynamically (Or build an `EXEC` string manually)

Comment: Your question sounds like is there a way to shoot in my foot? Why? When passing parameters to stored procedure you know for which parameter you're passing data, why not send the name along with it?

Comment: Ordinal parameter passing isn't generally desirable, and can cause a lot of [issues like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26547211/314291). If you really have to do this, then you can use [OleDb](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2407685/314291) instead of `SqlClient`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute a *command* instead, and pass in parameters '@p1', '@p2' etc:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = 'exec ' + StoredProcedure;

int i=0;
string comma = ' ';
foreach(var Param in Parameters)
   {
   var paramName = String.Format("@P{0}", i);
   cmd.CommandText += comma + paramName;
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, Param);
   ++i;
   comma = ', ';
   }
```

Be aware that `AddwithValue` is huge performance antipattern. See [How Data Access Code Affects Database Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx)

Comment: What is with SQL-Injection in this case?

Comment: @BendEg: what is? Is still a parameterized execution and no SQL is built from user input.

Comment: @RemusRusanu for educational purposes can you explain the need for the comma variable in your above code please.  Thanks!

Comment: Also what code do you suggest as an alternative to using AddWithValue?

Answer (score 3):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.parametername.aspx):

> The ParameterName is specified in the form @paramname. You **must** set
>   ParameterName before executing a SqlCommand that relies on parameters.

[Another](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) MSDN article for `SqlCommand`:

> Nameless, also called ordinal, parameters **are not supported** by the
>   .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server.

So answer is no, there is no way to execute a stored procedure without naming the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean some thing like **derived parameter**. This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx) gave an overview:

> Parameters can also be derived from a stored procedure using the
>   DbCommandBuilder class. Both the SqlCommandBuilder and
>   OleDbCommandBuilder classes provide a static method, DeriveParameters,
>   which automatically populates the parameters collection of a command
>   object that uses parameter information from a stored procedure. Note
>   that DeriveParameters overwrites any existing parameter information
>   for the command.

A nother solution would be to get the parameter of the stored procedure from the sql-database and than set them in your code. But this need one extra query. To get the parameter use:

```
select * from dbo.parameters where specific_name='procedure-name'
```

But in any case, you have to use parameter-names.