# Oracle ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework Database.SqlQuery binding parameters by position?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I have the following code:

```
        var query = Database.SqlQuery<int>(@"

            SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 
                FROM v$session v, UsersXxxx u
                WHERE v.Client_Info LIKE u.UserName || ';%' 
                AND v.UserName = :schemaName
                AND u.SchemaName = :schemaName
                AND v.module = 'XXXX.exe' 
                AND u.UserKey = :userKey)
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS LoggedIn FROM DUAL",

            new OracleParameter("schemaName", schemaName),
            new OracleParameter("userKey", userKey));

        return query.First() != 0;
```

Which produces a "ORA-01008: not all variables bound". I suspected something was up with the way the variables are being bound and ended up trying this:

```
        var query = Database.SqlQuery<int>(@"

            SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 
                FROM v$session v, UsersXxxx u
                WHERE v.Client_Info LIKE u.UserName || ';%' 
                AND v.UserName = :schemaName
                AND u.SchemaName = :schemaName
                AND v.module = 'XXXX.exe' 
                AND u.UserKey = :userKey)
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS LoggedIn FROM DUAL",

            new OracleParameter("asdf", schemaName),
            new OracleParameter("fdsa", schemaName),
            new OracleParameter("userKey", userKey));

        return query.First() != 0;
```

Which works like a charm! I poked around docs and found a blurb that says:

"Binding scalar parameters is supported with ODP.NET and Entity Framework. In Entity Framework, parameter binding by name is supported. Binding by position is not supported."

Somehow I think the docs are lying to me and it's trying to bind by position. I remember fixing this once long ago before the EF support, but I cannot remember what the fix was, much less how to apply the same technique in EF.

My workaround, although kludgy, works but isn't there an option somewhere to make it bind by name instead of by position? If so, what is it?

Comment: I'll give it all i got to find out :/

Comment: @Halter, no I still haven't found how to make this work the way I want. The workaround is still place, and honestly I pretty much gave up on it. It would certainly still be nice to know. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, the work around doesn't even work for me :(

Comment: James, do you know what version of EF you were using?

Comment: @Halter What version of EF are you targeting?

Comment: @IvanStoev EF 5

Comment: @Halter Too bad. This excludes command interception based techniques. The problem is that `SqlQuery` is bypassing the provider and uses directly `DbConnection.CreateCommand`, which in ODP leads to `OracleCommand` with `BindByName = false` (default).

Comment: @IvanStoev that's exactly what i feared was happening, it seems like the only solution (for EF5) is to concat the parameters in to the query with a sanitize function, or upgrade to EF6 which I am currently in the process of doing. It's proving to be a nightmare.

Comment: @Halter Eventually another option is to roll your own `SqlQuery` method replacement which creates a correct command, does `ExecuteReader` and then use the old good `ObjectContext.Translate` to get the result.

Comment: @IvanStoev Given the limitations at hand I think that's an acceptable solution, if you want to post it and example as an answer I would be happy to accept it

Comment: @Halter I'm on EF6.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `Database.SqlQuery` methods uses the `CreateCommand` method of the underlying `DbConnection`. In ODP.NET this leads to a `OracleCommand` which by default binds parameters by position ( `BindByName = false` ).

That behavior is not configurable and there is no good place for changing it. As a workaround, I could suggest using a custom `SqlQuery` method replacement, which would create the `OracleCommand` with `BindByName = true`, do `ExecuteReader` and use the `ObjectContext.Translate` method to do the mapping:

```
public static class EFExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DbQuery<T>(this DbContext db, string sql, params object[] parameters)
    {
        if (parameters != null && parameters.Length > 0 && parameters.All(p => p is OracleParameter))
            return OracleDbQuery<T>(db, sql, parameters);
        return db.Database.SqlQuery<T>(sql, parameters);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> OracleDbQuery<T>(DbContext db, string sql, params object[] parameters)
    {
        var connection = db.Database.Connection;
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        ((OracleCommand)command).BindByName = true;
        command.CommandText = sql;
        command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
        connection.Open();
        try
        {
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            using (var result = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Translate<T>(reader))
            {
                foreach (var item in result)
                    yield return item;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
            command.Parameters.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

In order to use it, simply replace

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<..>(...)
```

call with

```
context.DbQuery<..>(...)
```

Answer (score 7):

In in a recent version of the managed driver you are able to add a `web.config` entry that sets BindByName to true by default.

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
<version number="*">
  <settings>
    <setting name="BindByName" value="true" />
  </settings>
</version>
</oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro!!! It is so amazing to set the `bindbyname` to `true` by default in the config. You are amazing